# ASP.NET C# Programatically convert video on the fly

Tags: c#, asp.net, video

I want to convert video as it is uploaded to H.264 or an alternate HQ video to play in a flash player. I would like to support as many file formats as possible.

Can anyone recommend a tool. Thanks

**EDIT:** Need to be compatible on a Windows shared hosting account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/MPlayer.html) and Interop that with C#. I know a lot of websites use it to convert uploaded files to flash.

Comment: Does not look Windows compatible. I should have and have put that in my post.

Comment: Scroll down and look at the ports section, there is indeed a windows port of MPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

To display a H.264 encoded video in Flash, you can just change your extension to .flv.
In other cases, when you realy need to covert your video, you can take a look at [Sharpffmpeg](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpffmpeg/files/).

Answer (score 0):

Look into DirectShow filters, and WMEncoder (Windows Media Encoder) if you have the appropriate codecs installed, you can interface with DirectShow and WMEncoder to re-encode files.